# Use wp_get_recent_posts with search term

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, search, recent-posts

I have a function that uses `wp_get_recent_posts()` I need to use this same function on my search page but am having problems adding the search parameter to the `$args` array.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to implement it?

here is my function

```
function recent_articles_grid( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'numberposts'   => 6,
        'offset'        => 0,
        'featured'      => null,
        'trending'      => null,
        'showdate'      => null,
        'category'      => null,
        'showauthor'    => null,
        'init'          => 1,
        'searchterm'    => null
    ), $atts ) );

$args = array(
        'numberposts' => $numberposts,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'category__not_in' => array(391),
        'category' => $category,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

... additional code ...

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use this on your search page? If you're using search.php correctly, the main query/loop will already contain search results.

Comment: In the "additional code" section of the function I am building out a complex grid system and I would like to not have to rebuild this on the search template but instead utilize the function I have already built.

Comment: Your question should then be how to get posts from the main query into your layout function. Otherwise you're just needlessly performing the search twice, and you're going to be the next person running into issues with pagination, because you're not using the loop and template hierarchy properly.

Comment: ok, understood. so your answer then is this is NOT recommended which is the path I was heading down, however, I am still curious if it is even possible.

Comment: It should just be a matter of setting the `'s'` argument of `wp_get_recent_posts()` (or just `get_posts()`) to the search term, but yeah, I wouldn't suggest this method of display search results.

Comment: I already tried the 's' argument but that did not work.

Comment: Hmm, correction the 's' argument did work.

Comment: Jacob, turn your comment into an answer and I will star it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be a matter of setting the `'s'` argument of `wp_get_recent_posts()` (or just `get_posts()`) to the search term:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => $numberposts,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'category__not_in' => array(391),
    'category' => $category,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    's' => $searchterm,
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
```

But yeah, as discussed in the comments, I wouldn't suggest this method of display search results. If you're using search.php correctly, the main query/loop will already contain search results.

A better question might be how to get posts from the main query into your layout function. Otherwise you're just needlessly performing the search twice, and you're going to be running into issues with pagination, because you won't be using the loop and template hierarchy properly.